How can I catch the event after some actions like adding attribute, changing background color?
I faced some difficult issues.
Here is HTML code.
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
        ----------------
           **A**
        ----------------
      <script>
   </head>
   <body>
      ...
      <div id="myDiv">Hello word</div>
      ...
      <script>
            ... ...
            seTimeout(() => {
               let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
               myDiv.setAttribute('color', 'green')
            }, 5000);


      </script>
   </body>
</html>


in A area, I have to handle some actions after adding color attribute on .
How can I handle this problem?
To catch event, I tried to use window.addEventListener but it did not go well.

I don't know how you intend to change the color, like if you click on something and it change or you just want your page to load the div in that color.  Perhaps you could add a button, so when it is clicked the color changes.  Then you can get the event from the button you just clicked.
And then you could do something like this:
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);


Thank you for your answer.
But I can not change the other code and I can only insert code in A area.
